# I want to add more tab bar than two

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

I want to add more tab bar than 2 and I tried the make segue between the main storyboard but I can not succeed.Summary how can I add more tab bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add UITabBarItem programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675044/how-to-add-uitabbaritem-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna add more View Controllers via Storyboard:

1. Select your `UITabBarController`
2. Press down Ctrl key (hold on)
3. Drag to another View Controller (hold Ctrl)
4. Select `view contollers` in `Relationship Segue`
   [image: Select <code>view contollers</code> in <code>Relationship Segue</code>]
   Result
   [image: Result]

If you wanna create `UITabBarController` with `Storyboard Reference` you can use this approach:

1. Add TabBarController to your Storyboard.
2. Remove added View Controllers.
3. Add Storyboard Reference as many as you need [image: Storyboard Reference]
4. Select `view contollers` in `Relationship Segue` like in first approach  [image: Storyboard Reference with UITabBarController]